# Make P Tag Ignore Parent Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble with my off-canvas menu. when the menu opens, the p tags in it seem to change their left margin as it expands. I want my p tags to completely ignore the opening and closing of the menu and maintain their text alignment. Here's an idea of what I want it to do: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push

Compare that to my current code:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("burger").style.left = "260px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("burger").style.left = "10px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  madding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: width 1.5s;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

nav p {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  margin: 30px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav p:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.burger {
  will-change: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</span>
  <p>Home</p>
  <p>About</p>
  <p>Blog</p>
  <p>Contact</p>
</nav>

<span class="burger" id="burger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

Essentially, I want the p tags to act as if they are positioned absolutely, but be centered when the nav expands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your `<p>` tags in another `<div>` which will be statically positioned whether or not `<nav>` moves. Then apply your center-aligning to it:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("burger").style.left = "260px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("burger").style.left = "10px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  madding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: width 1.5s;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

nav p {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  margin: 30px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#pHolder{
   margin-left: 75px;
   width: 80px;
   text-align: center;
}
nav p:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.burger {
  will-change: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</span>
  <div id="pHolder">
  <p>Home</p>
  <p>About</p>
  <p>Blog</p>
  <p>Contact</p>
  </div>
</nav>

<span class="burger" id="burger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.

Comment: Same to you. Nice outstanding menu @H.Allen. you're welcome

Answer (score -1):

Instead of changing the `width`, keep the width constant and change the `left` alignment of the `nav`

Try this

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.left = "0px";
  document.getElementById("burger").style.left = "260px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.left = "-250px";
  document.getElementById("burger").style.left = "10px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  madding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -250px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: left 1.5s;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

nav p {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  margin: 30px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav p:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.burger {
  will-change: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</span>
  <p>Home</p>
  <p>About</p>
  <p>Blog</p>
  <p>Contact</p>
</nav>

<span class="burger" id="burger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

Comment: This isn't really what I want. You'll notice in the link I gave that the nav "links" ignore the side nav altogether. So, they remain in the same position the whole time, while the nav expands and contracts.

Comment: In w3schools, they have kept the content `left` aligned, while you have tried using the `center` align. So when you change the `width` of the `nav`, so ,of course, the content would also move according to the `width`.

Comment: Right, that's why I'm looking for a solution that bypasses this behavior. I was thinking something involving absolute positioning...